# Value with the highest frequency in a particular field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out a way to get the value with the highest frequency in a particular field.

Is there a built-in MongoDB command that can help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

```
db.getCollection('tweetsprocessed').aggregate([
    {"$group" : {
        _id:"$principal_topic",
        count:{$sum:1}
        }
     },
     { $sort : { count : -1 } }

])
```

it's similar to use GROUP BY and ORDER BY on SQL